# Guzzle 6, put request and description json

Tags: guzzle, guzzle6

I use guzzle 6 with a json file to describe my methods to call.

Bellow, an example with a put request :

in the json descriptor file :

```json
"putObjects" : {
    "httpMethod": "PUT",
    "uri": "objects",
    "summary": "Send objects to the api",
    "parameters": {
        "objects" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "location" : "body"
        }
    }
}
```

in the symfony controller :

```php
$clientResponse = $client->execute(
    $client->getCommand("putObjects", array(
        'objects'       => $request->getContent()
    ))
);
```

Before, with guzzle 3 when the put request was sent, the data sent was formated like this (a valid json) :

{objects: [{....}]}

But now, with guzzle 6, the data is formated as :

objects = {objects: [{....}]}

And of course my api send me an error 'Invalid json message received'.

Someone has an idea about this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

In symfony controller :

```php
$content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

$clientResponse = $client->execute(
    $client->getCommand("putObjects", array(
        'objects'       => $content['objects']
    ))
);
```

In the json descriptor file :

```json
"putObjects" : {
    "httpMethod": "PUT",
    "uri": "objects",
    "summary": "Send objects moderated",
    "parameters": {
        "objects" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "location" : "json"
        },
    }
}
```